# Ajax Delete not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form in which displays pictures(among other things).I want to delete the picture shown by using a "delete" button which will be displayed beside the image.Upon clicking the button, the image would be deleted from my database, after which the image would be removed from the form.

To achieve that, i am thinking of using an onclick function on the delete button which would initiate an AJAX call which would delete the image from the database.I will then proceed to remove the image from the form(via jquery .remove() ).

While i know what i have to do, my code does not seem to be working, hence my posting here on stackoverflow.

Errors:
Nothing is happening when i click on the delete buttons.

It would really help if someone could point out where i'm going wrong.

Thanks!

My Code:

Main page:

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}

if($_SESSION['auth']!=="yes")
{
    echo"You are not authorised to view this page. Please login <a href='login.php'>here</a>";
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<!--Links to Css Page-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<!--Loads JQuery script-->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!--edits list of item categories on page load-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edititemtable").hide();
    $("#edititemsubcat").hide();
    $("#edititemdetails").hide();
    $("#edititemcat").load("getcategory.php");

    $("#edititemcat").change(function(){
        var cat=$("#edititemcat").val();
        $("#edititemsubcat").show();
        $("#edititemsubcat").load('getsubcategory.php?cat='+cat);
    });

    $("#edititemsubcat").change(function(){
        var cat=$("#edititemcat").val();
        var subcat=$("#edititemsubcat").val();
        $("#edititemdetails").show();
        $("#edititemdetails").load('getitem.php?cat='+cat+'&subcat='+subcat);
    });

    $("#edititemsubmit").click(function(){
        var cat=$("#edititemcat").val();
        var subcat=$("#edititemsubcat").val();
        var item=$("#edititemdetails").val();
        $("#edititemtable").show();
        $("#edititemtable").append($("#details").load('changeitem.php?cat='+cat+'&subcat='+subcat+'&item='+item));

    });


    //Loads the Categories
    $('#changeitemcat').load("getcategory.php");
    //Loads the SubCategories
    $("#changeitemcat").change(function(){
        var cat=$("#changeitemcat").val();
        $("#changeitemsubcat").load('getsubcategory.php?cat='+cat);
    });
    //Deletes the existing pic via AJAX
    $("#changeitempicdel0").click(function(){
        alert("SUCCESS");
    });

});



</script>

</head>
<body style=" width:500px">
<form id="edititem" name="edititem" method="POST" action="getitem.php" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="edititemcat" name="edititemcat"></select>
            </td>


            <td>
                <select id="edititemsubcat" name="edititemsubcat"></select>
            </td>



            <td>
                <select id="edititemdetails" name="edititemdetails"></select>
            </td>



            <td>
                <input type="button" id="edititemsubmit" name="edititemsubmit" value="Get Item" />
            </td>


</form>

<table id="edititemtable" border='1'>

<tr>
    <td colspan='2'>Item Info</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Select Category: </td>
    <td>
        <select id='changeitemcat' name='changeitemcat'></select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Select SubCategory: </td>
    <td>
        <select id='changeitemsubcat' name='changeitemsubcat'></select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="details" name="details">
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Extract of form page(changeitem.php)

```
//NOTE:$imagecount is used to provide a unique id to each of the images loaded,     starting from index 0, increasing per loop.
//E.g changeitempicdel0,changeitempicdel1,changeitempicdel2, etc.
$imagecount=0;
WHILE($showpic=$getpic->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{


echo"<div id='image'.$imagecount>";
        $image=$showpic['Path'];
        $imageid=$showpic['ImageName'];
        echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo"Image";
            echo"</td>";

            echo"<td>";

                echo"<input type='hidden' id='changeitempicchangeid'$imagecount value=$imageid />";
                echo"<input type='button' id='changeitempicchange'$imagecount value='Change Picture' />";

            echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";

        echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td></td>";
            echo"<td>";
                //Displays image
                echo"<img src=$image id='image'$imagecount width='250' height='250' alt=''>";
                //Passes image id, used for deletion
                echo"<input type='hidden' id='changeitempicdelid'$imagecount value=$imageid />";
                //Delete button
                echo"<input type='button' id='changeitempicdel$imagecount' value='Delete' />";

            echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        echo"</div>";
        $imagecount++ ;

    }
```

Processing page(deletepic.php)

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
session_start();
}

if($_SESSION['auth']!=="yes")
{
    echo"You are not authorised to view this page. Please login <a href='login.php'>here</a>";
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

include("cxn.inc");
$picid=$_POST['pid'];
$picdel=$cxn->prepare("DELETE FROM `testdb`.`itempic` WHERE `PicID`=:picid ");
$picdel->bindValue(":picid",$picid);
$picdel->execute();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And don't see any #changeitempicdel0 element. I'm quite sure you need to delegate event or your selector is wrong.

Comment: Where is the delete button and its code?

Comment: @A.Wolff The #changeitempicdel0 element is = changeitempicdel$imagecount where imagecount is the number of rounds the loop has ran, giving each image a different id.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan the delete button is under changeitem.php, the button's id is "changeitempicdel"

Comment: please provide next time the rendered html, not the server side code which makes your posted code quite unreadable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class and delegate event:

```
$(document).on('click','.myclass',function(){
    alert("SUCCESS");
});
```

Here, it delegate to document level, you should instead use the closest static container element of the delete button. It is just hard to find which element reading your code...

PHP:

```
//Delete button
echo"<input class='myclass' type='button' id='changeitempicdel$imagecount' value='Delete' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You've hardcoded changeitempicdel0 in the click function. You need to add click events for each element.

For example, the function could be :

```
$(".fooClass").click(function(){
        ...
    });

        echo"<input type='button' class="fooClass" id='changeitempicdel'$imagecount value='Delete' />";
```

- there are many other things that can be improved in the code. Sql Injections being one of them.

Comment: I've tried using classes instead of ids, but the same problem persists.Nothing happens when i click on the button, even though the classes/ id is the same?